# HTTP Post responds with JavaScript

Tags: c#, http-post

I've tried this http post a few different ways and it always responds with the script at the bottom of this post. I also wrote some code in VBA that posts to the same URL and it responds as it should. One of my co-workers thinks the VBA code works because it's using the IE engine with JS enabled. Is there something else I need to do in C# to get this to work?

```
private static string TransformCmodReport(string ReportPath, string ModelPath)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://usflcmd1:80/RMSClient/RequestTypeAnalyze/AnalyzeRequest");

    string postData = "REQUEST_TYPE=E" +
        "&REPORT_HOST=usflcmd1" +
        "&REPORT_PATH=" + ReportPath +
        "&MODEL_PATHS=" + ModelPath +
        "&DEFAULT_VIEW=XLS_TABLE" +
        "&EXPORTTO=CSV";
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    return responseString;
}
```

the response...

> window.location =
>   '/RMSClient/Login/LoginIndex?returnUrl=%2FRMSClient%2FExportMode%2FTryExport%3FappId%3D1abfc958-2694-42b9-a006-49ca5b786e44'

Edit: Here's the VBA code that's working

```
Public Function GetReportData(ReportPath As String, ModelPath As String) As String
    Dim strRequest As String
    Dim http As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

    strRequest = "REQUEST_TYPE=E" & _
                 "&REPORT_HOST=usflcmd1" & _
                 "&REPORT_PATH=" & ReportPath & _
                 "&MODEL_PATHS=" & ModelPath & _
                 "&DEFAULT_VIEW=XLS_TABLE" & _
                 "&EXPORTTO=CSV"

    'Open the connection
    http.Open "POST", "http://usflcmd1:80/RMSClient/RequestTypeAnalyze/AnalyzeRequest", False


    http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    'Send the payload
    http.send CStr(strRequest)

    'Get the response/error
    GetReportData = http.responseText

End Function
```

Comment: That JS being returned is telling the client it needs to redirect to a log-in screen.  If this appear in the browser, it would redirect automatically.  You probably need to request/post data (username/password) to LoginIndex first, then use the cookies and headers returned for your request to the other page

Comment: That sounds like what my coworker suggested. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!